# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: result.main is undefined

Tags: javascript, promise, fetch-api

I am working on a weather based API project to sharpen my skills, but while fetching data i am getting a error:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: result.main is undefined

Here is the function responsible for fetching data from API:

```
async function fetchData(cityName) {
  const API_KEY = 'MY_API_TOKEN';

  const fetchRes = {
    method: 'GET',
    redirect: 'manual',
    mode: 'cors',
  };
  const response = await fetch(
    `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${cityName}&appid=${API_KEY}`,
    fetchRes
  );
  const result = await response.json();
  const data = result.main.temp;
  console.log(data);
}
```

Fixed using this call:

```
fetchData("london");
```

Here I am taking city name using another input and search button.

**Note: I hide my API token key for Security Reasons so that's not the issue.**

Comment: When you `console.log(result);`, do you see `{ main: ..., ... }`? (The error is caused by your trying to access `result.main.temp` while `result.main` is undefined)

Comment: @ChrisG yes when i `console.log(result);` it logs an object containing `{main: {temp:...}}` (after using `result.json()`)

Comment: I tested your code using my own key and it works as-is.

Comment: @ChrisG it worked when i hardcoded city name in the fetch url but it stopped working after i add a search option

Comment: I can reproduce the error if I pass an empty string as `cityName`, in that case the reply is `{ cod: "400", message: "Nothing to geocode" }`

Comment: @ChrisG yeah but am getting this error even with genuine city names like london and mumbai

Comment: What is the exact output of ```console.log(result)``` ?

Comment: @Pranaya it gives me object like this `Object { coord: {…}, weather: (1) […], base: "stations", main: {…}, visibility: 10000, wind: {…}, clouds: {…}, dt: 1622471146, sys: {…}, timezone: 3600, … }`

Comment: 1. I've been unable to reproduce this. It is not possible to get this output and still get the error you have mentioned. 2. The only time I am able to reproduce this error is when the API call itself returns a 401 (and not the output you have mentioned)

Comment: When calling `fetchData` you aren't correctly passing the content of the search field or whatever. The function in your question is working as expected. Please post the code that calls `fetchData` or this question will get closed as "not reproducible"

Comment: @ChrisG After some struggle on my mind i finally found the answer it still shows me the same error but atleast it is working i will post my answer

Comment: The proper answer here would be something along the lines of `if (result.main) { ... }`, i.e. checking the object exists before trying to access its properties). There's really no need to post an answer here; this isn't going to help anybody else. This was a very basic mistake and specific to how you called the function elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

**separate effects**

`return` the result instead of logging it -

```js
async function fetchData(cityName) {
  const API_KEY = 'MY_API_TOKEN';

  const fetchRes = {
    method: 'GET',
    redirect: 'manual',
    mode: 'cors',
  };
  const response = await fetch(
    `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${cityName}&appid=${API_KEY}`,
    fetchRes
  );
  const result = await response.json();
  return result.main.temp // <-- return the result
}
```

Now attach effect and error handler -

```js
fetchData(...)
  .then(console.log)      // <- receives data
  .catch(console.error)   // <- receives error
```

You can attach both the effect and error handler in a single `.then` -

```js
fetchData(...)
  .then(console.log, console.error) // <- same behaviour as above
```

**separate concerns**

And I would recommend separating concerns to make it easier to read/write your functions -

```js
const getJSON = (url, opts = {}) =>
  fetch(url, opts).then(r => r.json())
```

Now you don't have to repeat yourself every time you want to query some JSON -

```js
async function fetchData(cityName) {
  const API_KEY = 'MY_API_TOKEN';

  const url = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${cityName}&appid=${API_KEY}`

  const opts = {
    method: 'GET',
    redirect: 'manual',
    mode: 'cors',
  };

  const result = await getJSON(url, opts) // <- reusable function
  return result.main.temp
}
```

**URL handling**

I would advise against building URLs using strings. Instead use the URL [searchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/searchParams) API to construct things programmatically -

```js
async function fetchData(cityName) {
  const API_KEY = 'MY_API_TOKEN'

  // use URL api
  const u = new URL("https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather")
  u.searchParams.set("q", cityName)
  u.searchParams.set("appid", API_KEY)

  const opts = {...}

  const result = await getJSON(u, opts) // <- pass URL object
  return result.main.temp
}
```

As you can see it would be annoying to have to write all of that each time you need to set/modify some URL parameters. Applying the lesson from above, we write `href` -

```js
function href(url, params = {}) {
  const u = new URL(u)
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(params))
    u.searchParams.set(key, value)
  return u.toString()
}
```

Now you can avoid repetitive and error-prone code in common functions -

```js
async function fetchData(cityName) {
  const API_KEY = 'MY_API_TOKEN'

  // use our href helper
  const u = href("https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather", {
    q: cityName,
    appid: API_KEY
  })

  // use getJSON helper
  const result = await getJSON(u, {...})
  return result.main.temp
}
```

```js
fetchData("someCity").then(console.log, console.error)
```